# Editing API Documentation in CDK

Tags: amazon-web-services, aws-api-gateway, aws-cdk

In the AWS Documentation for API Gateway, there are ways to edit your API documentation in the console. Working in CDK, I can't find any way to achieve the same thing. The goal is to create the exact same outputs.

*Question 1:*
See [API Gateway documentation in console](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/developerguide/api-gateway-documenting-api-quick-start-with-console.html). This shows how you can edit pretty much everything you need to get nice headings and so on in your swagger / redoc outputs. But I can't find any way of inserting chunks of yaml / json into the doc in cdk.

*Question 2:*
Is it possible to prevent your exported OAS file from including all of the options methods? I want to automate the process of updating the API docs after cdk deploy, so it should be done as part of the code.

*Question 3:*
How can you add tags to break your API into logical groupings. Again, this is something that is very useful in standard API documentation, but I can't find the related section in cdk anywhere?

Really, I think AWS could knock up a short petstore example to help us all out. If I get it working, perhaps I'll come back here and post up one of my own with notes.

Comment: It might be an easy task if CloudFormation supports creating API doc. Otherwise, you have to do it via custom resource.

Comment: You need to use cdk lower level construct CfnDocumentationPart for documentation of apis. 
https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cdk/api/latest/docs/@aws-cdk_aws-apigateway.CfnDocumentationPart.html

Answer (score 0):

**Question 1 & Question 3:**

```
  
import * as apigateway from 'aws-cdk-lib/aws-apigateway';

//https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/api/API_DocumentationPart.html
   new apigateway.CfnDocumentationPart(this, 'GetDocumentationPart', {
      location: {
        method: 'GET',
        path: '/my/path',
        type: 'METHOD',
      },
      properties: `{
        "tags": ["example"],
        "description": "This is a description of the method."
      }`,
      restApiId: 'api-id',
    });

    //https://docs.aws.amazon.com/apigateway/latest/api/API_DocumentationVersion.html
    new apigateway.CfnDocumentationVersion(
      this,
      'DocumentationVersion',
      {
        documentationVersion: 'generate-version-id',
        restApiId: 'api-id',
      }
    );
```

Notice that you need to generate a version to publish the documentation changes. For the version value, I'll suggest generating a UUID.

According to the example above, the GET /my/path will be grouped by the "example" tag at a Swagger UI.

**Question 2:**
No, it is not possible.

I solved it by creating a lambda function listening to the api-gateway deployment event, getting the JSON file from the api-gateway via AWS SDK, parsing it for removing unwanted paths, and storing it in an S3 bucket.